# Run Jar file from C#

Tags: c#, java, process, executable-jar

Given code was a part of the code used to run a jar file on c# environment. [Complete Code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=42121)

```
strArguments = " -jar "+ Argument list;          
processJar.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + @"java" + "\"";
processJar.StartInfo.Arguments = strArguments;
processJar.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory =; \\Give the working directory of the application;
processJar.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processJar.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

I know that processJar.StartInfo.FileName should contain the jave.exe so that the respective file will be triggered when the process gets started. But the above given code also runs successfully.

Question:
What does   **"\"" + @"java" + "\""** here? If I provide such input will the system itself will search java.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They simply ensure that the string will be `"java"` (with the quotes).

This is normally needed when you have a path that contains spaces.

Windows requires the path to be quoted if it contains spaces (for example `"C:\Program Files"`).

As for finding the executable - if the path to the java executable is in the `%PATH%` environment variable, it will be found.

In this case they seem superfluous.

Comment: Ok! If I have the %PATH% environment variable correctly set, then I need not worry about the java.exe when I run by jar files?

Answer (score 0):

its the exe name which needs to be launched

Comment: Well! I know it but how does the system know where my exe is? I am talking about the file path here