# How to run jar file form C# code

Tags: c#, java

I am new to `C#` and tying to run jar file from C# code. But it seems that jar file is not opening and command prompt disappers very quicky as I am unable to see any error messgage.

Here is my code ,

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "D:\\DATA\\PROJECT\\LicensingManagement\\Assignment\\JavaLogin.jar";
myProcess.Start();
```

Can any one put me in right direction ? Whats wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: I am not sure,whether it is opening or not.

Comment: Your code is fine, your java command is not. To run a jar, you need to run: `java -jar <name>.jar`

Comment: This looks almost duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427371/run-jar-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1 , but it deals with path to the `java` executable... You still may be interested in it as it shows complete correct code.

Comment: @RGraham except `java` may not be in the PATH...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov And `D:\\DATA` may not exist. But hey, I can't fix all the worlds problems - just the obvious ones ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to provide -jar switch to java command.

For example, the command to execute JAR file is,

```
java -jar D:\\DATA\\PROJECT\\LicensingManagement\\Assignment\\JavaLogin.jar
```

So you may try,

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar D:\\DATA\\PROJECT\\LicensingManagement\\Assignment\\JavaLogin.jar";
```

Comment: thanks  it's working.  But it seems that command prompt is also opening with jar file , is there any way to open jar file without opening command prompt.

Comment: @user3556028 Please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments. Open another question.

Comment: @user3556028 use `javaw` to run without the console

Comment: Doesn't it work, "myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true" ?