# Can I use a Java API (JAR file) in a C# application without any tool?

Tags: java, c#, .net, interop

I need to call a Java API (JAR file) in a C# application.
Is it possible to call a Java API without using any tool like IKVM?

I don't want to be depending on any tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run jar file form C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753060/how-to-run-jar-file-form-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Does not seem like a duplicate, this question seems to ask how to use an API, not simply execute a jar code. Some clarification might be required.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a duplicate as I am aksing about any way to call jar files in c# not how to run it.

Comment: NaeiKinDus , could you tell me which type of clarification should I add ?

Comment: Why do you don't want to use existing and working solutions? Don't reinvent the wheel...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c

Comment: Mischa Behrend My Cient has sent me an api java to use so I need to call it  in my c# code

Comment: StefanE, the answer of the post you give is to use ikvm but as I said in my question I shoudln't use any other tool.

Comment: Why? **Why** do you not want to use IKVM?

Comment: I will depend on this tool and my client doesn't accept that I depend any other tool so I need wheter to tell him that it's possible wheter it's not but without using any  other tool.

Comment: reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/512247/4273199) answer, there are two options to use IKVM. First: use a tool from them to "convert" your `.jar`into a `.dll` and reference that in your C# project. (Work is done without thirdparty software, **in execution**) | Second: Use their tool to reference the `.jar` directly... (not what you want)

Comment: do you know why your client doesn't want third party tools?

Comment: I think he doesn't want to depend on any tool that's why I have to respect his decision. 1- For converting .jar to .dll I have 3 files .jar and I was not able to convert 2 of them to .dll but only to .exe So I don't know if the solution ikvm for converting will help me ?. 2- do you know any way just by using some lines of c# codes for using jar files?

Comment: 1 - That probably while these .jar files have a `Main()`-Method defined... which makes them executables...

Comment: 2 - No, I do not know a easy way to do this... Addition to 1 - You can reference `.exe` files the same way as `.dll` files