# How do I include a JAR file in my C# project?

Tags: java, c#, wpf, jar

I have the following problem:

I am currently writing a WPF application for my thesis and this application needs to call a JAR file. I cannot switch completely to Java because I am using a library that only works in C#.

During my research regarding this problem I stumbled upon ikmv, but it is not supported anymore and I cannot convert my JAR into a DLL, because I need at least Java 11.

Right now I am looking into calling the JAR directly from my program, but I wanted to ask if there are any other ways how I can use a JAR file in my project.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [SO Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753060/how-to-run-jar-file-form-c-sharp-code)

Comment: That is what I am currently looking into, but I was wondering if there is another way to dot it or maybe a library or something I have not found yet.